# Control Ubuntu volume of computer from Android phone

Tags: ubuntu, audio, android

I am looking for a way to access my Ubuntu box from my android phone. In particular to change the volume.

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 LTS and Android 4.2.2 I have super user access to the computer. I'm not so sure about the phone. Its pretty much out of the box.

Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried? What version of Android? What version of Ubuntu? Are you a Super User on either one?

Comment: "Is this possible?" It probably is, but we'd really like more details on your setup. You are very unlikely to get an answer this way. Please read [ask] and edit your question.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt sure what to include. Updating niw

Comment: Would something like this help? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inspiredandroid.linuxcontrolcenter&hl=de

Answer (score -1):

With a remote control app, like [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/), you can do this and more.